# "Invalid background description file" when using opencv_createsamples

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to train my own Haar cascade classifier following [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/). I am able to successfully create bg.txt for negative images. However when I run opencv_createsamples I am facing the error: Invalid background description file.

These are the approaches I have already tried:

1. [Appending a new line after each file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610142/opencv-createsamples-invalid-background-description-file)
2. [Giving full paths.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290024/opencv-createsamples-invalid-background-description-file)
3. [copy pasting it to a temp.txt and running that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378638/opencv-invalid-background-description-file) In this case the opencv creatsamples does not show any error. However info.txt does not seem to have anything written in it.
4. [Converting the encoding to ASCII.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378638/opencv-invalid-background-description-file/)
5. reinstalling opencv.

This is my bg.txt:

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.1490g.jpg/

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.996g.jpg/

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.485g.jpg/

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.995g.jpg/

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.535g.jpg/

/home/icts/Faces/neg/cat.513g.jpg/

Successful execution and creation of info.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Invalid background description file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378638/opencv-invalid-background-description-file)

Comment: Do you mean reinstalling opencv? I did that but the error still persists.